# Load data again after segue is done

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I would like to know how should I behave if I got several articles in table view controller, which are loaded and parsed from some API. Then I would like to click on some article to view his detail.

Should I load all articles on start up with all data and then pass concrete whole article to next detail table controller or just send article id and in new table controller load again whole one article with passed id?

I think that is much better second method, but have no idea how to do it. Any help? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: added code

MainTableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let articleId = articles[indexPath.row].Id
    let destination = DetailTableViewController()
    destination.articleId = articleId

    destination.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Main", sender: self)
}
```

DetailTableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

    // Vyzkoušíme jestli jsme připojeni do internetu
    if Helper.hasConnectivity() {
        // Zapneme načítací obrazovku
        setLoadingScreen()

        // Načteme jídla
        loadMainArticles()
    } else {
        promptAlert(title: "Upozornění", message: "Ujistěte se, že Vaše zařízení je připojené k internetu")
    }
}

private func loadMainArticles() {
    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchArticle(part: "GetArticle", articleId: "brananske-posviceni--spravna-lidova-zabava-s-pecenou-husou") { (articles: [Article]) in
        self.removeLoadingScreen()

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine

        if articles.count == 0 {
            self.promptAlert(title: "Upozornění", message: "Žádná data")
        }

        self.selectedArticle = articles[0]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

ApiService:

```
func fetchArticle(part: String, articleId: String, completion: @escaping ([Article]) -> ()) {
    var Id = ""
    var Title = ""
    var Content = ""
    var Picture = ""
    var PublishDate = ""

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://xxx")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)

            var articles = [Article]()

            for dictionary in json as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
                .
                .
                .

                let article = Article(Id: Id, Title: Title, Content: Content, Picture: Picture, PublishDate: PublishDate, Categories: Categories)

                articles.append(article!)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                completion(articles)
            })

        }

        }.resume()

}
```

The problem is that when I do the segue after click on row, then should loadMainArticles. The method is triggered, but always stops on URLSession row and immediately jump to resume() and the completion block is never triggered. Is there any reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a choice that should be done according to article data model size.

You should pay attention to which data you need to show on TableView single cell and which on Article detail page.

I suppose you to show:

- Title and posted hour in TableView
- Title, hour, long description, maybe some image in Detail page

In this case i would reccommend you to download only title and hour for each article item, and then, in detail page, download single item details (avoid to download unused content, since user could not open every item).

Otherwise, if amounts of data are similar, download all informations on first connection and open detail page without making any other network request.

> I think that is much better second method, but have no idea how to do it.

You need to retrieve article id from TableView selected cell and pass it to DetailPageViewController using prepareForSegue. In DetailPageViewController ViewDidLoad send article id to your backend api and retrieve article details to show.

Comment: I have done this like you said in loading all articles. In ViewDidLoad I call API method GetAllArticles ( using URLSession.shared.datatask ) and always return to completion block what I want, but when I run this after segue in PageDetailTableViewController where I passed article id via segue, then method always stops on first line (URLSession.shared.datatask) and then jump to .resume() So no completion block is triggered... This is the problem which I facing...

Comment: You should use prepareForSegue method to set articleID to new detail controller

Comment: Thanks! I have already solved the problem... The problem was not in API service method which was serving data, but in method cellForRowAtIndexPath.. I tried to populate table, but the instance of article was empty. So I add only If let statement and everything worked well as I expected. I did not get that the render of table and APIService method run on different thread...